# How to solve the following? $ x^3+1=2{(2x-1)}^{1/3} $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

Find all the real solutions of
$$x^3+1=2{(2x-1)}^{1/3}  $$

> I tried to cube both sides but got messed up with a nine degree equation! Please help.
>   Thanks in advance!

Comment: x=1 is a solution by observation

Comment: Also, any integral solutions must be odd numbers, so replacing $x=(2*n+1)$, we see there are no other integral solutions possible, except for n = 0

Comment: @Holographer. Only $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ I suppose since, because of the rhs, $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes indeed; the other root solves the 9th order polynomial but not the original equation

Comment: @Holographer. This is the classical problem of squaring or cubing which generates fake solutions. Cheers. ):

Comment: @Holographer I'm afraid that you are incorrect about $x \ge \frac{1}{2}$ since cube roots can have negatives inside them as well. Also, checking with wolfram alpha, both $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ are the solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**We are given**

$$x^3+1=2{(2x-1)}^\frac{1}{3}$$

Substitute $(2x-1)=y$

$\implies x^3=2y-1$

Also,

$y^3=2x-1$ [Using the initial substitution]

Subtracting the above two equations, we get,

$x^3-y^3=-2(x-y)$

$\implies x=y$

or,

$x^2+xy+y^2=-2$

But since $x^2+y^2 \ge xy$ and **L.H.S.** is thus positive,

$\implies x^2+y^2+xy=-2$ yields no solution.

Now, as $x=y$,

$\implies x=(2x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$\implies x^3-2x+1=0$

Now, using **rational root theorem,** $x=1$ satisfies the above equation. So, by **dividing with $(x-1)$,** we obtain

$(x-1)(x^2+x-1)=0$

$\implies x=1,\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ are the required solutions.

Comment: Rigorous and clearly explained. +1

Answer (score 5):

Write your equation as $$\frac{x^{3}+1}{2}=(2x-1)^{1/3}$$
Now notice that these are *inverses* of each other. That is, $y=\frac{1}{2}(x^{3}+1)$ is a reflection of $y=(2x-1)^{1/3}$ in the line $y=x$. By symmetry, then, any root must also lie on $y=x$. The easiest way to write this is $$\frac{x^{3}+1}{2}=x \implies x^{3}-2x+1=0$$
Which factorises to $$(x-1)(x^{2}+x-1)=0$$
No heavy machinery required!

Comment: Great solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x)=x^3+1-2{(2x-1)}^{1/3}$$ It is only defined for $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$. If you compute the second derivative $$f''(x)=6 x+\frac{16}{9 (2 x-1)^{5/3}}$$ it is always positive. So, the maximum number of roots is $2$. Since $x=1$ has been identified by inspection, it means that $f(1-\epsilon) \lt 0$ and since $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{9}{8}>0$, there is another root located between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$.

As Holographer wrote, the root corresponds to $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ but I do not know how to find it without knowing the result in advance.

But we can compute it using Newton method. Starting at $x_0=0.6$ and using the classical quadratic scheme $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac {f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ the successive iterates are $0.616459$, $0.618022$, $0.618034$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Comment: It is also defined for $x \le \frac{1}{2}$. I think you accidentally mixed the cube root and square root properties.

Comment: @Samurai You beat me by 14 sec :)